# Printing the pojo object values in the zul file using struts1

Tags: struts, zk

i integrated struts 1 with zk. i set the list of pojo values in the form of action execute method.how i can get this values in the zul file.Any idea please

Thanks
Usman

Answer (score 0):

You can store the pojo values in a session scope or request scope and then receive them in the same way from the zul file.

Please refer to this [List of Implicit Objects](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Implicit_Objects#List_of_Implicit_Objects)